# How to change array size for TwitterUtils?

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark, spark-streaming, twitter4j

I'm using Apache Spark with TwitterUtils and I am sending in an array:

```
JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc, auth, array);
```

Is there any way I can change the array? Say for example I am sending {"a", "b", "c"}, and I want to make the stream look for {"a", "b", "c", "d"} without having to restart the stream.

I tried making the array instantiated as being 100 large and adding to the next element as the more things are to be added to look for, but all the `null` values in the array cause an error.

I also tried doing this:

```
public void changeStream(String searchterm){
    array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length+1);
    array[array.length-1] = searchterm;
}
```

I read somewhere that I can make the array point to another array with a larger size but that doesn't seem to return anything at all.

If someone can lend some help that would be great. Thanks :)